# react-admin edit component is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-admin

I have been following the tutorial on [react-admin](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Tutorial.html) and when I get to the part where you have to edit, a user for instance, the edit page shows up black with no errors in the devtool window. Please have a look at my code. Where am I going wrong?

in App.js

```
<Admin dataProvider={dataProvider} authProvider={authProvider}>
    <Resource name="users" list={ UserList } layout={ MyLayout } edit={UserEdit} create={UserCreate} />
  </Admin>
```

in UserList.js

```
export const UserEdit = (props) => {
  <Edit  {...props}>
    <SimpleForm>
      <ReferenceInput source="id" reference="users">
        <SelectInput optionText="id" />
      </ReferenceInput>
      <TextInput source="firstName" />
      <TextInput source="lastName" />
      <TextInput source="email" />
      <TextInput source="organization" />
      <TextInput source="status" />
    </SimpleForm>
  </Edit>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem here:

`<Resource name="users" list={ UserList } layout={ MyLayout } edit={UserEdit} create={UserCreate} />`

`layout` is an `Admin` prop, It shouldn't be in a `Resource`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have moved the layout prop but still getting an empty edit page for the user when I click the edit button.